# Ubuntu 20.04: Force fractional scaling functionality in virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, vmware

I've set up an Ubuntu 20.04 desktop instance using VMware. Since 20.04, fractional scaling is not an experimental feature any more, but nonetheless works only on resolutions commonly used by display vendors, may it be a resolution or an aspect ratio thing.

When using an VM, there's plenty of possible resolutions in VMware, dependent on the hosts' window size. Is there a way to force fractional scaling constants (125%, 150%, etc) to be displayed on **every** resolution?

I'm aware of using it fullscreen and use full display resolution, but that's not the smart way all the time.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: As requested, I've added some screenshots.

[This is using a common 2560x1600 resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T80A.png), you can see the scaling buttons (100%, 125%, 150% a.s.o)

[This is the screenshot running an odd resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd0Nf.png) originating from the VMware window size, so set by host. The scaling buttons are missing.

I want the buttons to be displayed on *every* resolution. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot to your question that will show what you want? I have Ubuntu 20.04 in VMware Workstation V15 in a Window (not full screen). I can see the various resolution in Display Settings and even with Fractional Scaling Enabled, I do not see anything under each resolution

Comment: @John, please see the added imgur links in the original post. Thank you.

Comment: That is similar to what I see in my virtual machine, that is, no buttons at each resolution, so about all you can do.

Comment: Same in Ubuntu 22.04 under VM Ware player. Fractional scaling not available at non-standard screen resolutions and reset to 100% when changing screen size.

Answer (score 1):

The scaling feature remains experimental and then further in a Virtual Ubuntu machine, the scaling option is not even available and I believe this is because of the virtual display hardware.

I am quite sure that you need a real (physical) Ubuntu machine for this to work.

Comment: Fractional Scaling is available for me when running Ubuntu 22.04 under VMware Workstation 17.  In my specific case it only seems to be available using the preset resolutions in the dropdown, not if I manually resize the VM guest window to any other resolution.

Comment: My answer was two years ago and VMware and Ubuntu have changed since.

Answer (score 0):

In VMware® Workstation 16 Pro I had to enable "Stretch Mode" under Display Settings. You can access the VM's settings with CTRL+D.

Changing the settings require a restart to take effect.